# Critical points of function $\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$- reading material reccomendation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

I am looking to widen my knowledge in the analysis of critical points for functions $\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$.
All the textbooks I've encountered so far only consider $\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ when it comes to critical points. For $\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ I only find chapters on line and surface integrals. 
Specifically, I am interested in how to recognize a critical point using the Jacobian, how to classify it using the Hessian, and what is the geometric meaning of each point.
Can you recommend a book that covers these topics?

Comment: A critical point for a differentiable function $f:U\subset \Bbb{R}^m\to\Bbb{R}^n$, where $U$ is an open subset is by definition a point $p\in U$ such that the linear transformation $Df(p):\Bbb{R}^m\to\Bbb{R}^n$ is not surjective (equivalently the Jacobian matrix does not have full rank). In the special case of $n=1$, this is equivalent to requiring $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^1}(p)=\dots =\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^m}=0$. Also, when $n>1$, you can't talk about maxima/minima (afterall, what does it mean to say one vector in $\Bbb{R}^n$ is smaller than another?) anymore.

Comment: This is why one usually focuses on $n=1$. Here we can talk about a critical point being a local maximum/minimum etc, and talk about second derivative tests using the Hessian.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you for your answer. To the best of my knowledge, in the case n>1 there is also classification (for example degenerate and non-degenerate points, which is defined using the Hessian matrices of the n scalar-functions in the mapping). Specifically, I am interested in when having a critical point at $p\in U$ that corresponds to the direction $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$ means that I can't step in the direction $v$ when in $p$.

Comment: degenerate and non-degenerate critical points are defined when $n=1$; it is the domain that we allow to be multidimensional (i.e we allow for $m\geq 1$). For $f:U\subset \Bbb{R}^m\to\Bbb{R}$, we define a critical point $p\in U$ (i.e where $Df(p)$ is not surjective, or as I mentioned above, in this special case of $n=1$, it's equivalent to $Df(p)=0$) to be degenerate/non-degenerate if the Hessian matrix is not invertible/invertible respectively.

Comment: In general the second derivative/Hessian is a bilinear map $D^2f(p):\Bbb{R}^m\times\Bbb{R}^m\to\Bbb{R}^n$. When $n=1$, this can be dualized to obtain a mapping $\Bbb{R}^m\to(\Bbb{R}^m)^*$, and hence by choosing the standard basis, we get an $m\times m$ matrix (the Hessian at $p$). But, when $n>1$, there's no way to "cheat" by dualizing and think of $D^2f(p)$ as a matrix. We can't talk about invertibility anymore. So, we can't further classify them (atleast I haven't seen any such further classification/definitions).

Comment: ok, so say that in a given point $p$ the jacobian $J(p)$ of the mapping $f: U\in\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ has a null space, and say that $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector s.t $J(p)v=0$. If I denote by $H_i$ the $n$ hessian matrices of $f$, what can I deduce from the sum $v_i H_i$? Can I say something about the geometry of $f$ in the point $f(p)$? Can I determine whether I can step in the direction $v$ from $f(p)$?

Comment: Note that $J$ having a non-trivial kernel is not enough to be considered a critical point. (eg if $f:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$, $f(x,y)=x$, then it's derivative at every point is $(1\,\,\,0)$ which clearly has kernel, in fact spanned by $(0\,\,\,1)$, but the derivative everywhere is nonzero, in particular it is surjective).  "What can I deduce from the sum $v_iH_i$", I'm not too sure. Also your last question isn't clear, what do you mean by "whether I can step in the direction $v$"? Why can you not move along any direction from $f(p)$?

Comment: Note that non-degenerate critical points for real-valued functions are pretty well understood due to Morse lemma, but otherwise, it's a pretty tough subject (again I'm not super knowledgeable about this, so perhaps someone else can shed more light). I'd suggest before looking at what happens when $n>1$, you understand the $n=1$ case, since that's already non-trivial. (also I just realized the order of $m,n$ in the post and title are different, so please edit your title).

Comment: What I mean is this: given a small ball $B$ around the point $p$ I want to know if the image $f(B)$ contains a small ball around $f(p)$. This would mean that by taking a small step from $p$ I can step in any direction around $f(p)$. Is this clear?

Comment: Also, I did not understand your example for non-trivial Kernel not being enough. Note that $v$ is in the image plane, and has a size $m$ (maybe I should first state that $m<n$). In your example, the only $v$ that will give $Jv=0$ is $v=0$.

Comment: oh no definitely not. It is possible for $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ to be $C^{\infty}$, vanish on a ball $B$ in the domain (hence $f(B)=\{0\}$, so doesn't contain an open ball/interval), even though $f\neq 0$ (i.e there exist some $q$ such that $f(q)\neq 0$). Google bump functions; this is just one instance of how bad degenerate points are. As for my example, it is correct the way I have stated it ($m=2,n=1$, $f(x,y)=x$), but previously you didn't impose the condition $m<n$. If you impose this condition, then sure $p$ is a critical point if and only if $J(p)$ has a non-trivial kernel.

Comment: Thanks again. I am aware that it I possible in general, but I am trying to understand when can I determine that this is not the case ( I have a specific function f that I am exploring). For example, if it was $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, then by looking at the eigenvalues of the hessian and finding both negative and positive values, I could determine that there are only saddle points, and hence for any point t$p\in\mathbb{R}^n$ I can always find a direction $v$ to step in from $p$ such that $f(p)<f(p+\epsilon v)$, and also a direction $u$ such that $f(p+\epsilon u)<f(p)$. Agree?

Comment: Yes that's right, so in this one-dimensional target space case, if you have both positive and negative eigenvalues in the hessian, then your image contains a small interval around $f(p).$

Comment: Great, so I wonder how this condition generalizes to multiple dimensions

Comment: This opens the door to the Pandora's box of singularity theory. For a somewhat elementary exposition, look at Guillemin and Golubitsky's *Stable Mappings and their Singularities*.

Comment: In addition to @TedShifrin's recommendation, have a look at C. G. Gibson's "Singular points of smooth mappings". Not as comprehensive, but very friendly and gentle. The point is the classification of singularities by Hessian does not quite work for $\Bbb R^n$-valued functions; you miss out on a "large" class of degenerate singularities which occur frequently unlike for $n = 1$. For example, $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$, $(x, y) \mapsto (x, y^3 + xy)$, the cusp, is degenerate, but in fact occur frequently (observe crumpled bedsheets or curtains!).

Comment: Thank you both, from a brief look these books seem to be exactly what I needed. A small question about what you've said @BalarkaSen: when you say that hessian-based classification "miss out" do you mean that it can only mistake in one direction? i.e. if I did happen to get mixed values for the weighted sum of Hessians, then the critical point is degenerate for sure?

Comment: @user3350919 I mean to say that nondegeneracy of the Hessian is too restrictive a condition for higher dimensions; it automatically forces the singularity to be quadratic, whereas "generic" singularities can be worse than quadratic eg cubic like the cusp above. It is a fact that "generic" singularities of maps to $\Bbb R$ cannot be worse than quadratic, so you do not "miss out".